# VB.net check if program is in startup?

Tags: vb.net

so i have this code

```
 My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).DeleteValue("WooW")
```

But before i perform that code i wanna see if that program / key is in startup
can any one help me with that? please

Comment: So your question is how to check a registry key?

Comment: i wanna check if the key is on / Enabled
and if it is enabled / on then i wanna disable it

Comment: So you want to know how to lookup a value in the registry, right?

Comment: I wanna check if the startup value is there / if startup value / program is enabled, and if it is on / enabled i wanna disable it

Answer (score 1):

```
Using subKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
    If subKey.GetValue("WooW") <> Nothing Then
        subKey.DeleteValue("Woow")
    End If
End Using
```

If a value does not exist the *GetValue()* function will yield **Null** signified using **Nothing** in Visual Basic. If you want, you could pass a second argument to *DeleteValue()* that will cause the function to throw should the value not exist `subKey.DeleteValue("Woow", True)`

Comment: Error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `If subKey.GetValue("Woow") <> Nothing Then`.

Comment: It was because Caster by mistake spelled the word 'Microsoft' wrong. I corrected it and you can check now. I know it's too late...